# How to capture multiple photos and display them as a gif

Tags: ios

This question has multiple parts.

How can I alter this code, to take multiple photos (10 for instance) and put them in an array and display them as a gif?

I "kind of" did this, but separately; one program that captures a regular photo and saves it to the camera roll (CAMERA), and another that takes photos that are already saved on the Xcode project, puts them into an array and displays them as a gif (GIF).

Here's the regular camera code:

```
#CAMERA
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error : NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }

    if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            captureSession?.startRunning()

        }


    }


}
@IBOutlet var tempImageView: UIImageView!

func didPressTakePhoto(){

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {


                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

                let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                self.tempImageView.image = image
                self.tempImageView.hidden = false

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

            }


        })
    }


}


var didTakePhoto = Bool()

func didPressTakeAnother(){
    if didTakePhoto == true{
        tempImageView.hidden = true
        didTakePhoto = false

    }
    else{
        captureSession?.startRunning()
        didTakePhoto = true
        didPressTakePhoto()

    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    didPressTakeAnother()
}




}
```

Here's the GIF code:

```
#GIF
-(IBAction)play{

image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5331.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5332.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5333.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5334.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5335.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5336.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5337.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5338.JPG"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5339.JPG"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_5340.JPG"],nil];

[image setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];
image.animationDuration = 1;
[image startAnimating];

}

-(IBAction)stop{

    [image stopAnimating];

}
```

Comment: Your "GIF" code has nothing to do with a GIF. It's just an animated image view.

Comment: how would you recommend I create a gif application?

Comment: Well, instead of saving the images with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` in `didPressTakePhoto`, store them in an array. Then use that array in you `play` function.